# Why GridView is showing only one column?

Tags: android, gridview

I am creating a dinamically GridVew to display an icon and some text. I want to have at least 2 columns but it displays a single column, just like a ListView.

This is my GridView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/gridView1"
  android:numColumns="2"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:columnWidth="100dp"
  android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</GridView>
```

And for each row I have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/row_icon"
    android:layout_width="150px"
    android:layout_height="150px"
    android:layout_marginRight="50px"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/row_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:maxLines="2" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Each row is inlfated in my custom ArrayAdapter :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_icon);
    textView.setText(values[position].getName());

    asyncDownloadAndSetImage(values[position].getInfo().getThumbnail(), imageView);

    return rowView;
}
```

Tried to tweak the layouts but it still shows only on one column like this:

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my activity was extending `ListActivity` not `Activity` as this was converted from a `ListView`

Answer (score 0):

Probably your problem is

```
//GridView 
android:columnWidth="100dp"

//ImageView
android:layout_width="150px"
android:layout_height="150px"
```

The image is larger than the space that you put in the size of each column.

Test Test these changes with

in row.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/row_icon"
    android:layout_width="100px"
    android:layout_height="100px"
    android:layout_marginRight="50px"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/row_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:maxLines="2" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried with smaller image with no success. I shrinked the image down to 10dp but sill it displays on single column. It's displayed like this: ![Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/LR9NMOi.png)

Comment: change you LinearLayout to vertical